# first mint free second x price wrong calculation

Tags: nft, erc-721

I have a contract where the first mint is free and every mint after that is 0.001 ETH per token.

1 mint in a transaction goes fine costing nothing but gas.

2 mints in a transaction goes fine also costing 0.001 ETH + Gas.

But when i want to mint 3 the price is 0.003 ETH  instead of 0.002 ETH and 1 NFT being free resulting in error "Invalid ETH value sent.".

```
uint256 public  maxSupply = 2222;
uint256 public  MAX_MINTS_PER_TX = 25;
uint256 public  PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE = 0.001 ether;
uint256 public  NUM_FREE_MINTS = 2;
uint256 public  MAX_FREE_PER_WALLET = 1;
uint256 public  freeNFTAlreadyMinted = 0;

constructor() ERC721A("Lg", "Lg") {}

 
function mint(uint256 numberOfTokens) external payable
{

    require(isPublicSaleActive, "Public sale is paused.");
    require(totalSupply() + numberOfTokens < maxSupply + 1, "Maximum supply exceeded.");

    require(numberOfTokens <= MAX_MINTS_PER_TX, "Maximum mints per transaction exceeded.");

    if(freeNFTAlreadyMinted + numberOfTokens > NUM_FREE_MINTS)
    {
        require(PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE * numberOfTokens <= msg.value, "Invalid ETH value sent. Error Code: 1");
    } 
    else 
    {
        uint sender_balance = balanceOf(msg.sender);
        
        if (sender_balance + numberOfTokens > MAX_FREE_PER_WALLET) 
        { 
            if (sender_balance < MAX_FREE_PER_WALLET)
            {
                uint free_available = MAX_FREE_PER_WALLET - sender_balance;
                uint to_be_paid = numberOfTokens - free_available;
                require(PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE * to_be_paid <= msg.value, "Invalid ETH value sent. Error Code: 2");

                freeNFTAlreadyMinted += free_available;
            }
            else
            {
                require(PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE * numberOfTokens <= msg.value, "Invalid ETH value sent. Error Code: 3");
            }
        }  
        else 
        {
            require(numberOfTokens <= MAX_FREE_PER_WALLET, "Maximum mints per transaction exceeded");
            freeNFTAlreadyMinted += numberOfTokens;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The condition is wrong

```
PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE * numberOfTokens <= msg.value
```

When `numberOfTokens` is 3, it will require `msg.value` to be greater than `0.001 * 3 = 0.003`.

If you want the first to be free then it should be something like

```
PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE * (numberOfTokens - 1) <= msg.value
```